# How to update a List of Maps in DynamoDB table via boto3?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

is there any way to update/change value of a attribute as map nested in a list. My table looks something like this

```
       {
  "MainId": {
    "S": "8981d9d0-373d-4f30-8084-cc4e18f9855f"
  },
  "date": {
    "S": "8/11/2020"
  },
  "user_id": {
    "S": "xyz@gmail.com"
  },
  "role": {
    "S": "normal"
  },
  "finale": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "Hatch_type": {
            "S": "P7684"
          }
```

I would like to change the update the value of 'Hatch Type' map in the 'finale' list. Please note that the provided table is not complete.

My current code looks like

```
import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime


#TABLE_NAME = "table1"


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name="us-east-2")
    
    client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name="us-east-2")
    
    TABLE_NAME = dynamodb.Table('table1')
    
    response =  TABLE_NAME.update_item(
        Key={
            'MainId':'8981d9d0-373d-4f30-8084-cc4e18f9855f'
        }
        
        UpdateExpression='SET #finale[0].#Hatch_type = :newvalue",
        ExpressionAttributeNames = {
            
                   ??

            
            
        },
        
        ExpressionAttributeValues = {
            ???
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
        
    )
```

I'm stuck at this point and not sure how to proceed further. Please help.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

ExpressionAttributeNames = {
':newvalue': "P7686 //whatever you want to update it io"
},
ExpressionAttributeValues = {
'#Hatch_type': " Hatch_type"
},

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).